# Where is the dashboard in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I can't figure out where the dashboard is in Amazon Web Services.

There is something called 'AWS Management Console' but it is merely a menu page that lists all services offered by AWS for a specific server location. From there you must know the service to select, e.g. EC2 or S3, to get the details of that services for that specific location.

But aren't there any dashboard page that gives an overview of all the services enabled across AWS?
So that a sys admin can see all EC2 instances running, S3 buckets sizes, etc., under 1 view?

Comment: Have you looked at any of the AWS documentation? That would be the place to start, if you're confused about the general AWS setup.

Answer (score 2):

AWS does not have a dashboard in the same way that Azure does. The closest would be Amazon CloudWatch which allows you to create a dashboard to monitor your services.

If you really want a fancy graphics based dashboard, look at some of the third party companies that provide dashboards for AWS.

I prefer the Amazon way. I know AWS very well, so I know how to quickly drill down to the services that I want to look at. I do see how this can be confusing for a new person to AWS. Like most things, once you are comfortable with a product or service, you start to understand its design and how to move around within its framework.